# Can we sort the characters of a string in SQL oracle?

Tags: sql, string, oracle, sorting

Can we sort the characters of string in SQL oracle
I have tried using orderby ,chararray,sort kind of functions not worked
please help me with this
Thank you

Comment: Show us some sample data, and how you want it sorted. (As properly formatted text, no images.) Also show us your current code attempt.

Comment: Why do you want to sort the characters?